# Using ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am confused, I have multiple parts of my Activity which I have to show one by one. I don't want to use Tab. So whether I should use ViewFlipper or divide my views into more Activities. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to have a complex applications split up in multiple activities each of which is responsible for a certain aspect for your logic.

Comment: Its not a complex app. Its a wizard like app in which the user will provide some input then click on Next button then give some details and then click on Next again or Finish.

Comment: My answer still applies. Each next _page_ in that wizard is responsible for something else.

Comment: Won't it unnecessarily increase the number of activities?

Comment: That doesn't matter. I mean why would that be important? Take a look at the default Android applications on [s.android.com](http://s.android.com). Always apply the KISS principle. Keep a single activity simple stupid.

Comment: ...then whats the use of ViewFlipper? Is it used only for animation?

Comment: It is used for switching between views. You seem to misunderstand the idea of a `View` and an `Activity`. Android development is not like web development where you have one screen on which you simple draw different content based on user interaction. In Android you are supposed to start another Activity to handle another part of the logic/app.

Comment: Yeah I already said I am confused. From what should I decide, whether to use an Activity or ViewFlipper?

Comment: You use a `ViewFlipper` when you want to display multiple images in one view for example. You start it and let if flip through your list of images. I've already described when to use an Activity. Basically I'd say don't bother thinking about when to use what, for the start go with a separate Activity for each part of your application, when time comes that you need a ViewFlipper you will know.

Comment: Thanks. Nice explaination. Now one unrelated question. How much experience of Android development do you have? :)

Comment: Quite a bit, if you want to chat join the [Android Lounge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/520/android-lounge-no-so-questions). ;)